# Python find Nth prime

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, primes

I am trying to find the nth prime number, without looking at other solutions I am building this function

```
def Nth_Prime(Target):

    Primes = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19]
    Num = 20
    N=8
    Count=0

    while(N<Target):
        for i in Primes:
            if Num%i==0:
                Num+=1
                i=2
            else Num%i!=0:
                Count+=1
                if Count==len(Primes):
                    i=2
                    Primes.append(Num)
                    N+=1
                    print(Primes)
                    Num+=1
                    print(Count)

Nth_Prime(10002)
```

Now, while it may not be the most efficient, what I am trying to understand is why I can't reset my variable I to the beginning of the array for each loop? the function correctly finds 23 as the next prime number then it goes wrong

help appreciated.

EDIT: I got it! Thanks to all, time to clean it up a little and make it more aesthetic

```
def Nth_Prime(Target):

    Primes = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19]
    Num = 20
    N=8
    Count=0
    x=0

    while(N<Target):
        i = Primes[x]
        if Num%i==0:
            Num+=1
            x = 0
        elif Num%i!=0:
            Count+=1
            x+=1
            if Count==len(Primes):
                Primes.append(Num)
                N+=1
                Num+=1
                Count = 0
                x=0
    print(Primes[10000])

Nth_Prime(10002)
```

Comment: for loop overrides the value just before starting the loop.

Comment: you are iterating trough a list, so in the next iteration your `i` will be the next value in the list, no matter what you did with it before, use a while loop instead and indexing instead

Comment: Because that's just the way `for` loops work in Python. You can do whatever you like with `i` inside the loop, but it will get set to the next value from `range` (or whatever you're iterating over) when you get back to the top of the loop.

Comment: I will return with an edit with my attempt at a while loop

Comment: Hm, so how would I use a while loop whilst still using my array of primes?

Comment: BTW, `else Num%i!=0:` is invalid syntax. You can't give `else` a condition. If you need to do that, use `elif`. However, there's no need for a condition there. If the `Num%i==0` condition is false then `Num%i!=0` _must_ be true, and vice versa.

Comment: You can keep using your `for i in Primes:` loop. But instead of doing `i = 2`, use `break` to exit the inner loop, after you finish incrementing `Num` and printing stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No matter what you do with `i` variable in the loop `for` is going to reinitialize it with the next value from `primes` list. That's just how the for loop works.

so you can imagine the first line of `for` loop to be

```
for loop:
    i = Primes[x] # initialize
    ... # do stuff
    x+=1
    i = 'something' # HAS NO EFFECT for next iteration
```

Comment: Better post it as a comment, just like you already did ;)

Comment: This seems like a proper answer to "why I can't reset my variable I to the beginning of the array for each loop"? I was considering writing an answer very similar to this one.